# Anchor won't work (goes to the # but doesn't move)

Tags: html, css, anchor

Nothing I try to find online works. When I hover over the link it goes to the link and the url changes but it doesn't move the page. I'm using chrome up to date.

Here is the code:

Edit: Apparently it has something to do with the CSS because when I took the CSS out it started to work, but I don't know why

```js
$('.scroll').localScroll();
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  color: #222;
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header::after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#down{
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  width: 3%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.movetobot{
  height: 200vh;
}

section h1{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 110%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0.4em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}

.logo {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.btext{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #f9f3f4;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0.4em;
}

h1{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.btn{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto' sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 4em;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 85px;
  padding-top: 25px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

nav a::after{
  margin-top:5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
}

nav a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn:hover{
  color: #b19295;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="icon" href="/icons8-home-24.png">
  <title>Royal Services</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html"><h2 class="logo">R O Y A L</h2></a>
      <nav class="scroll">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Offering</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://discord.gg/tmkjepT">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- <hr width="100%"> -->
    <a href="#services">
    <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/634848-200.png" alt="down" class="hvr-hang" id="down">
  </a>
    <div class="btext">
      <h1>ROYAL SERVICES</h1>
      <a href="https://discord.gg/tmkjepT" target="_blank" class="btn">Discord</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="services">
    <section class="movetobot">

      <h1>Services</h1>

    </section>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-localScroll/2.0.0/jquery.localScroll.min.js></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Including your snippet of code would be easier to figure out the issue

Comment: I already posted answer but, your  inclusion of scrollto is missing quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Set the **`"id"`** to page part tag where you want to move.

```
<a href="#someIdName"></a>
<div id="someIdName"></div>
```

Comment: as I said before, it changes the link of the page to #services but does not move the page anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your content in `<div id="first">`  is either floating or position absolute that div have no high so `<div id="services">`  takes all of the page. When you click the link the page is already there.

What you can do is give min-height to `<div id="first">`.
What i would do is to structure the HTML in better way and remove all floats and absolute positions.